django-tables2: hyperlink in cells
I have a view named events displaying two columns. One eventType and a second eventDates, listing dates. It looks like this:



eventType
eventDate




foo
1900-01-01, 2010-02-02


bar
2000-01-01, 2010-02-02, 2010-03-03



The code for the view and the table looks like:
def events(request, pk):
    data = some_module.get_data(pk)
    data_table = MyTable(data)
    return render(request, "app/events.html", {"table": data_table})

Where data is a list of dictionaries and MyTable is a class inheriting from django_tables2.Table:
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    eventType = tables.Column()
    eventDates = tables.Column()

A cell in the column eventDate can be either empty or containing several dates. It depends on pk.
I can display that table. Now, I would like each date to be an hyperlink redirecting to another view. This view would be like that:
def event_details(request, eventtype=et, eventdate=ed):
    data_event = some_module.get_event data(eventtype, eventdate)
    return render(request, "app/events_details.html", {"data_event ": data_event })

And here are my issues. First, I have not been able to have a dynamic number of hyperlink, varying from cell to cell. Second, the url should include the eventType and its date. E.g. taking the exemple above, cliking on 2010-02-02 should redirect to either:
eventtype=foo_eventdate=2010-02-02 or eventtype=bar_eventdate=2010-02-02, depending on which 2020-02-02 I clik on.
I have first tried to have several links in one cell following some recomendations from e.g. django-tables2-linkcolumn-multiple-items-in-the-same-cell or using-linkify-option-on-django-tables2-columns-to-create-links but at the end of the day, my main issue are the ones stated above which I cannot find how to solve.

I don't have much information about the specific data and types used. However, if eventDate can be provided as a list, the following method can be adapted to display a link for each individual date. This should provide a solid foundation for resolving your issue.
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    event_type = tables.Column()
    event_dates = tables.Column()

    def render_event_dates(self, record, value):
        dates = []
        for date in value:
            event_url = reverse(
                "event_details",
                kwargs={"event_type": record.event_type, "event_date": date},
            )
            dates.append(f'<a href="{event_url}">{date}</a>')

        return mark_safe(", ".join(dates))


Thanks a lot. I should have specified it but eventDate is a list of dates which I actually convert to a string before calling data_table = MyTable(data) so I can definitivel try your approach.

I finally had the time to implement your approach and it worked quite well. So thanks a lot.
